# git forced command conq username

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have my account in [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and I created private repo in it. But when I try to push my code to my private repo, it gives me error of repo doesnot exists while it present.

On further investigating I found out that while I do any command on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), it fires force command

```
Remote: Forced command: conq username:<username>
```

In this, username is not mine. It belongs to a friend of mine. I don't know how this change was made.

How can I change this username or how can I stop this force command?

Comment: Does anything strike you as weird if you inspect `git config --list
`? Most likely you see it there. If you don't, you might want to check your ssh config as well.

Comment: I don't see any weird thing in `git confit --list`. And there is no ssh config file, from which I guess there is no extra agent to change the username?

Answer (score 1):

"ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa solved my issue"
[link to original q/a](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7741/another-conq-repository-access-denied)

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer this question, but I found my solution to this problem, as [simonxy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654015/simonxy) mentioned, that can be one way to solve the problem, but my case was a bit different.

I work at office where I am in need to use a particular private key to connect to server, and when each time I try to login using ssh, first it tries to login with this private key (since this would my first ssh key added to new system). Unfortunately someone else used this key pair to their bitbucket a/c which caused to login with their credential. And my private repo denied the request and got the error.

So I removed all my private key and added them again, this time my office private key was added later. :)

Hope this could help others who suffers similar problem :)